# Rails object duplicating using inverse_of. Still getting nested object validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have Sale and Request associated models. Here are their model codes:

```
    class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :requests, :inverse_of => :sale

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :requests

            validates :requests, presence: true

    end


class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale, :inverse_of => :requests
end
```

So I am trying to duplicate a Sale object that already has some Requests in it. I used inverse_of on both models, but still getting Validation error "Requests can't be blank".

Is there anything else I should do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was using amoeba gem and should have used amoeba_dup method instead of simple dup.